# Reading the content of a css file using Java

Tags: java, css, parsing, file-read

I am trying to read a css file, find out the css classes and their definition and then save it in a csv file with its class name and description. Using Java, the following I have css file, common.css.

```
/* CSS Document */

.Page
{
    background-color: #F4EEE0;
    background-image: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    scrollbar-face-color: #DEAC64; 
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF; 
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #805822; 
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #B47F36; 
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #805822; 
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #7188AA; 
    scrollbar-base-color: #F4EEE0; 
    scrollbar-track-color: #E8C490; 

}
a.PageLinkTrail 
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #805822;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.PageLinkTrail:hover
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #805822;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.IconSpacing a:hover
{
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    text-align:center;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #C99349;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C99349;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration:normal;
    vertical-align:Top;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:hand;
}
```

I want class name

```
.Page
a.PageLinkTrail 
a.PageLinkTrail:hover
```

Here is its definition.

```
{
    background-color: #F4EEE0;
    background-image: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    scrollbar-face-color: #DEAC64; 
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF; 
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #805822; 
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #B47F36; 
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #805822; 
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #7188AA; 
    scrollbar-base-color: #F4EEE0; 
    scrollbar-track-color: #E8C490; 

}
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #805822;
    text-decoration:none;
}

{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #805822;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I want to save it on a csv file. How should I use Java to get the CSS content such as name and definition? This is the part of the solution I am having most trouble completing at the moment.
I have written a flowing code

```
package com.tufan.digite.Count;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 public class GetAllCssFiles {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    try {       
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:/digite/work/digite/WEBUI/common/theme1/common.css");

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        FileChannel fc = fstream.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,(int) fc.size());
        Charset cs = Charset.forName("8859_1");
        CharsetDecoder cd = cs.newDecoder();
        CharBuffer cb = cd.decode(bb);          
        String strLine;                     
        String content = ".MainNav a:hover{ float:left; width:70px; height:65px; border-top: 2px Solid #F4E6CC; border-bottom: 2px Solid #805822; border-left: 2px Solid #F4E6CC; border-right: 2px Solid #805822; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; align:center; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; background:#C99349; background-image: url(../../images/hor_nav_bg.gif); background-repeat: repeat-X; padding:4px; clear:left; }";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z_0-9 | -|:|;|\n\t]*)(\\{[\n\t]*[a-zA-Z_0-9 | -|:|;|\n\t]*\\})");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(cb);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String selector = matcher.group(1);
            String definition = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("selector:" + selector + "Definition"
                    + definition);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }}
```

it will not give me group values.
if i pass **content** to Matcher it will give me ans ".MainNav a:hover" in group one and 
{ float:left; width:70px; height:65px; border-top: 2px Solid #F4E6CC; border-bottom: 2px Solid #805822; border-left: 2px Solid #F4E6CC; border-right: 2px Solid #805822; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; align:center; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; background:#C99349; background-image: url(../../images/hor_nav_bg.gif); background-repeat: repeat-X; padding:4px; clear:left; } 
as definition as group2

but that content is hardcode.
i am trying on **cb** cb contents whole css file content.

Comment: Read the file, parse content, get definitions. Simple!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: "...I am having most trouble completing at the moment" So do you mean to say that you have started to do some coding on this? Then show that and we can pointout what went wrong.

Comment: all this code just for splitting the css code with '{','}' and line breaks?

Answer (score 1):

Find position of first opening brace, find position of first closing brace, get text from beginning to opening brace, get text from opening brace to closing brace, repeat with text after closing brace until no more text is left.

Comment: Not quite, you seem to have ignored quoted strings.